# If soul and spirit are reversed in Lk.1:46&47, would it change the meaning?

Tags: luke, spirit, soul

Luke 1:46, 47

> <sup>**46**</sup> And Mary said,My soul doth magnify the LORD, <sup>**47**</sup> And my spirit hath rejoiced in God my Savior.

Are the words soul and spirit interchangeable in these verses, and if not: WHY?

Comment: Probably not.  But so what?

Comment: @Dottard I am trying to determine a clear difference between soul and spirit. If "I'm a soul man" from the song, is accurate biblically, then the soul has more to do with emotions and the flesh. This would point toward the spirit having to do with life souce. This context seems both are emotional. This question is for someone who has greater language skills than myself. Also I once heard a preacher define the spirit as the intellect of the soul. The reference material I have defined a spirit as a soul. I have read both Greek and Hebrew definitions according to Strong's, but still seems unclear

Comment: When I say " unclear" I am largely referring to when do you use the word spirit and when and where do you use soul in context?

Comment: That is not what your question is asking.  If you want to ask about the distinction between the use of the word psyche and pneuma, then ask that question.  However, since the meanings of these words overlap, and they are being used in synthetic parallelism, it probably would not make any difference in Luke 1:46, 47.

Comment: The way I look at it is that the bible speaks about two kinds of spirits. The first one is a spirit with a small “s”, and the second one is a spirit with a capital “S”. The first spirit is the soul, and the second is the Holy Spirit, also called “the Holy Ghost”. When the bible speaks about the tripartite human constitution; body, soul and spirit, I believe it means body, soul, and Holy Spirit. I base this idea partially on 1 Cor 2 and 1 Cor 15, and on Jude v.19

Comment: @ Constantthin Since you opened the door, I have long pondered on the lack of the Holy Spirit in unrepentant man.  Three thirds-one third= two thirds=.666 . The decimal point kind of blurs my theory.

Comment: @ Dottard Maybe parallelism, but I see nothing artificial.

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**: Mary's intent in this passage is to praise God. Whether or not there is a difference between "spirit" and "soul" the passage reflects Mary praises for the faithfulness and power of God - the meaning of the passage is the same.

The passage in context paraphrased:
Mary is pregnant with Jesus and she is visiting Elizabeth (v29)
Elizabeth is happy and excited for Mary and thrilled to have the visit (40-45)
Mary sings a beautiful and elegant song praising God that is a reflection of Mary's heart and speaks truth about God. (v47-55) The verses in question are part of Mary's song.

A lot has been written on the difference between psyche and pneuma.

- A trichotomist view is that people are made up of three distinct parts - body, spirit and soul. This means that there is some consistent and fundamental difference between spirit and soul.
- A dichotomist view is that people are made up of only two distinct parts - body and spirit/soul. In this view spirit and soul are interchangeable with each other.

For the passage in question:
Luke 1:46, 47

> 46 And Mary said, My soul doth magnify the LORD, 47 And my spirit hath
> rejoiced in God my Savior.

From the interlinear:
[Verse 46](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/1-46.htm)
[image]
[Verse 47](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/1-47.htm)
[image]

The word translated "soul" is "[psyche" in Greek](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/1-46.htm)
The word translated "spirit" is "[pneuma" in Greek](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/1-47.htm)

HELPS word studies:
[Psyche](https://biblehub.com/greek/5590.htm)

> 5590 psyxḗ (from psyxō, "to breathe, blow" which is the root of the English words "psyche," "psychology") – soul (psyche); a person's distinct identity (unique personhood), i.e. individual personality.
>
> 5590 (psyxē) corresponds exactly to the OT 5315 /phágō ("soul"). The soul is the direct aftermath of God breathing (blowing) His gift of life into a person, making them an ensouled being.

[Pneuma](https://biblehub.com/greek/4151.htm)

> 4151 pneúma – properly, spirit (Spirit), wind, or breath. The most frequent meaning (translation) of 4151 (pneúma) in the NT is "spirit" ("Spirit"). Only the context however determines which sense(s) is meant.
>
> [Any of the above renderings (spirit-Spirit, wind, breath) of 4151 (pneúma) is always theoretically possible (spirit, Spirit, wind, breath). But when the attributive adjective ("holy") is used, it always refers to the Holy Spirit. "Spirit" ("spirit") is by far the most common translation (application) of 4151 (pneúma).
>
> The Hebrew counterpart (rûach) has the same range of meaning as 4151 (pneúma), i.e. it likewise can refer to spirit/Spirit, wind, or breath.]

Looking at the definitions it's clear that - as usual - context drives meaning. Across scripture sometimes pneuma and psyche are used in the same way and sometimes they are not. For the case in question - Luke 1:46, 47 Mary is praising God from her whole spirit whether you are a dichotomist or not.

Comment: @ David D First off, thank you for your hard work and research. My Strong's dictionary 5590 Greek is psuche pronounced psoo-khay' indicating the u vowel. And yet in a Webster dictionary psycho Gr. psyche means -the mind or mental process ( as psychology) . Is psuche in the Stong's and your psyche the same?

Comment: According to the intralinear it is. I have updated my answer including images of both verses with full notation and links to the appropriate pages. Be careful when using Webster for biblical words. Their definitions are based on current popular usage. We want to know how the biblical authors are using words, there is often a huge difference.

Comment: @ David Not disagreeing; and thanks again, the biblical use seems to imply a much greater distinction than our reference material. Ex. Sharper than any two edge sword, able to divide spirit from soul.